# Karma/webpack TypeError: Cannot read property 'configPath' of undefined

Tags: webpack, karma-runner

I get the following error when I run my karma.config.js :

> [karma]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'configPath' of undefined
>       at D:\View\node_modules\karma-webpack-preprocessor\index.js:39:50
>       at nextPreprocessor (D:\View\node_modules\karma\lib\preprocessor.js:36:26)
>       at D:\View\node_modules\karma\lib\preprocessor.js:122:9
>       at module.exports (D:\View\node_modules\isbinaryfile\index.js:28:12)
>       at D:\View\node_modules\karma\lib\preprocessor.js:84:7
>       at D:\View\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:504:3)

My karma.config.js looks like this:

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
webpackConfig.entry = {};

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: false,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        autoWatchBatchDelay: 300,

        files: [
            './src/index.js',
            './**/*.spec.js'],

        preprocessors: {
            './src/index.js': ['webpack'],
            '.**/*.spec.js': ['babel']
        },

        webpack: webpackConfig,

        webpackMiddleware: {
            noInfo: true
        }
    });
}
```

The webpack config I try to reference in the karma.config.js works perfectly fine, when I use it with webpack alone.

So what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I had `karma-webpack-preprocessor` and `karma-webpack` in my node modules. They use the same preprocessor name `'webpack'`.

To uninstall `karma-webpack-preprocessor` and keep `karma-webpack`did the trick for me.

You could also keep `karma-webpack-preprocessor` but define the configPath like so:

```
webpackPreprocessor: {
  configPath: './config/webpack'
},
```

You can see that here: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-webpack-preprocessor